# 「と」I'm kinda confused with the usage of it here

Tags: grammar

I'm watching a show called "Erased", and there's this scene where the main character is talking with himself (he's talking in his mind, not out loud) and I'm wondering what's the function of 「と」here, I've discussed it before with some friends and they think this と is quoting here, but I'm not sure about it. What do you think? (I'm watching it on Netflix, and the English subtitles goes like "I'm scared I'll find out that I have nothing to offer the world.").

(About the discussion I had with my friends, we got something like "(There is nothing for me) confirming that is scary.").

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unequivocally a quotative-と used with 確認する. A bit more literal translation would be:

> <自分には何もない>と確認してしまうのが怖い。
>   I'm afraid to confirm <I have nothing>.

ないと can be conditional in other contexts (e.g., この本がないと出来ない = "I cannot do it *if* I don't have this book"), but 確認する is a verb that safely takes quotative-と.